# Get path hierarhy using connect by prior vertical instead of horizontal in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchy, connect-by

Hi I have an SQL statement using `connect by prior`. I want to get the path by specific `where` criteria. Following SQL works fine, but I don't want to get just a single row matching the criteria, I want also to get each parent record (vertically up the hierarchy).

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.CALCULATION_PLAN_CODE, '.'),4) CODE_PATH,
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME, ' > '),29) NAME_PATH,           
       R.CALCULATION_PLAN_CODE,
       R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME        
  FROM PRM.MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R
  WHERE R.RELATED_YEAR = :relatedYear
  AND R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID != 0
  AND REGEXP_LIKE (R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME,'ROL')
  AND  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF  = 1 
 START WITH R.OID =
          (SELECT R1.OID
             FROM PRM.MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R1
            WHERE (R1.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID IS NULL OR R1.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID = 0) AND R1.RELATED_YEAR=:relatedYear) CONNECT_BY_PRIOR  R.OID = R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID;
```

I don't want the output like this: [image: result by query]
I want it like this:

```
150       İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER
150.1     İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU
150.1.1   İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > ROL    <-----


150       İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER
150.1     İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU
150.1.1   İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > YAZI ARAÇLARI  
150.1.1.1 İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > YAZI ARAÇLARI > ROLLER KALEM    <-----
```

How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove `AND REGEXP_LIKE (R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME,'ROL')` maybe?

Comment: @Timekiller, If I remove it, how to search by name.I want to search by name using like operator,Then I am waiting to see one or more hierarhy tree like I showed above.

Comment: Is there anybody to comment it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution will need to address your table more than once, since your desired output can have duplicates: a partial path (e.g. "150.1") may lead to two different leafs of interest, so it will occur twice (or more).

Note that you don't need to repeat the `where` conditions in the `start with` clause. They are applied anyway, also for the starting records.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT NODE.CODE_PATH, NODE.NAME_PATH FROM
      (
      SELECT     OID,
                 SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.OID, ',') OID_PATH
      FROM       MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R
      WHERE      REGEXP_LIKE (R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME,'ROL')
                 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
                 AND R.RELATED_YEAR = :relatedYear
      START WITH NVL(CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID, 0) = 0
      CONNECT BY PRIOR  R.OID = R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID
      ) LEAF
INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT     SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.CALCULATION_PLAN_CODE, '.'),2) CODE_PATH,
                 SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME, ' > '),4) NAME_PATH,
                 OID,
                 SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R.OID, ',') OID_PATH
      FROM       MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R
      START WITH NVL(CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID, 0) = 0
      CONNECT BY PRIOR  R.OID = R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID
      ) NODE
ON NODE.OID = LEAF.OID
OR LEAF.OID_PATH LIKE '%,' || NODE.OID || ',%'
```

Result:

```
CODE_PATH   NAME_PATH
----------  ------------------------------------------------------------
150         İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER
150.1       İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU
150.1.1     İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > ROL
150         İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER
150.1       İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU
150.1.1     İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > YAZI ARAÇLARI
150.1.1.1   İLK MADDE VE MALZEMELER > KIRTASİYE MALZEMELERİ GRUBU > YAZI ARAÇLARI > ROL
```

And a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ef2fb/6).

The idea is that in a first sub-select you select the leafs, with the `where` conditions as you provided. Then you do another sub-select that selects *all* nodes with their paths, without any filtering. Finally you match those nodes as being in the line of descent of the first filtered leaf nodes.

Comment: It was a good attempt, but I think OP only wanted to show trees where *leaf* contained `ROL`. Even in your fiddle, it shows group with id 5, which contains other entries. Additionally, your query will show all groups not containing `ROL` because of `OR CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 0` - see yourself, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4e4f/1

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the query to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is rather complex, but it's solvable. You'll need to build multiple trees, though: with first query, you connect by *in reverse*, starting with leaf units, to build branches up to the root nodes, and keep track of the leaf you're building the branch for, using `connect_by_root` function. Then, in second query, you `connect by` based on the results of the first query, this time in proper order, but additionally matching on leaf id you kept track of earlier.

```
with Q as
(
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(R.OID) leafid, R.*
FROM MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R
CONNECT BY R.OID = PRIOR R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID
START WITH R.RELATED_YEAR = 2015
  AND REGEXP_LIKE (R.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME,'ROL')
  AND R.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID != 0
  /*Following condition is replacement for CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1,
    Since you're connecting in reverse you can't use it*/
  AND not exists 
    (select 'x' from MOVABLE_CALCULATION_PLAN R2
     where R2.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID = R.OID)
)

select SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Q.CALCULATION_PLAN_CODE, '.'),2) CODE_PATH,
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Q.CALCULATION_PLAN_NAME, ' > '),4) NAME_PATH
  from Q
  CONNECT BY PRIOR  Q.OID = Q.CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID
  and prior Q.leafid = leafid
  START WITH NVL(CALCULATION_PLAN_PARENT_OID, 0) = 0
```

As usual with connect by queries, performance might be an issue, but from what I saw on similar table structure it's still rather quick. See also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd5b68/6

P.S. in the future, be sure to provide us with sample data and decent description of your conditions, don't make us decipher your query and think up the samples ourselves.